# Using a variable to reference another database in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

I am trying to cycle through all rows in a table that holds the database name for another database. This is what I have which compiles but doesn't work as MySQL takes the 'database' bit as the actual database name rather than the contents.

How can I change the following so that it takes the contents of the variable?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CYCLE;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE CYCLE()
BEGIN
  DECLARE data_name CHAR(255);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR SELECT database FROM company;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  OPEN cursor_i;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO database;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SELECT * FROM database.table LIMIT 1;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;
END;
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Update: to be clear I know that 'database' is a reserved word. I have used that here in place of the actual variable name I have used.

Comment: See [9.2.1 Identifier Qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html), [9.3 Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) and [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: Not sure how this helps? Identifier qualifiers makes no mention of using variables. Ditto the guide on prepared statements. I get that 'database' is a reserved word but that was an example. I had already been through the documentation before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't evaluate the content on a variable on a table select statement, in that case you must build a query in a string an execute:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CYCLE;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE CYCLE()
BEGIN
  DECLARE data_name CHAR(255); -- unused?
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR SELECT database_name FROM company;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  OPEN cursor_i;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO data_name;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    -- now build the query before execute:
    set @sql = concat('SELECT * FROM `',data_name,'`.`your_table` LIMIT 1');

    -- and execute
    prepare stmt  from @sql;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt ;

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;
END;
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

*Would better not confusing us using variable names that causes more questions. #JustSaying

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I'd come to the same conclusion about having to execute but also decided it was just as easy to do in PHP ;-)